# require gets messed up if you are pointing at a symlink

Tags: node.js, git, requirejs

I am trying to create a plugin folder in my nodejs project.

```
/
 --/plugins
 ----index.js
```

The plugins folder has an index.js file that will dynamically 'load' all plugins that live in that directory.

I created a foo module

```
/
  --/plugins
  ----index.js
  ----/foo (foo plugin stuff all in this dir)
```

This is all working great.  Now I want to move the foo plugin into a different git repo.  Idea is that when you pull the core project you do not get any plugins by default.  But that you can 'install' them by dropping what you want into the plugins directory.

So I leave the plugins dir empty in git, I checkout a plugin in a different directory than core (so git will not pick this up as a change).  I then symlink the plugin into the plugins directory.

This is where I start to run into problems.  If I reference a module that lives in my core project from my foo plugin:

```
var someCoreModule = require('../core/someModule');
```

If that is from '/plugins/foo/someFoo.js'  and it goes up one directory that goes up one from where the plugin really lives on the filesystem, and not from where the symlink was.   Looking into this it looks like that is the correct result from nodejs perspective.

Question is how can I throw something into my plugins directory that is a git repo it self but not have the main server repo track the 'plugin' repo?

I think I can do something with git ignore, but wondering if there is a more elegant solution for this type of simple plugin architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The way I implement the plugin pattern in node is by using the [peer-dependencies](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/) field in `package.json`. This allows me to publish a core package to npm along with plugin packages that have the core package listed as a peer dependency.

Peer dependencies must be installed side-by-side rather than nested within the package's `node_modules` directory. Not sure if that helps your specific situation out but I think it's way more elegant than symlinks or git submodules, etc. [You can list github repos as dependencies as well](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies) if you don't want to publish to npm.

Take a look at my [shotgun-client](https://github.com/codetunnel/shotgun-client/blob/master/package.json#L30) package's `package.json` file. It lists my core [shotgun](https://github.com/codetunnel/shotgun) module as a peer dependency. If the user runs `npm install shotgun-client` they will also install shotgun side-by-side with it. So, instead of this:

```
/
  --/node_modules
  ----/shotgun-client
  ------/node_modules
  --------/shotgun
```

You end up with this:

```
/
  --/node_modules
  ----/shotgun-client
  ----/shotgun
```

By doing this you can always be sure of the directory structure. You need only go up one level into the `node_modules` folder into which they were installed, and then back down into your core package or any of your plugin packages.

Plus it's just way cooler to `npm install some-plugin` instead of `git clone some-plugin-repo-url` and then have to symlink that to a `plugins` directory. I'd say the former is far more intuitive :)

Also, removing the need for symlinks will make your packages work on Windows without trouble.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, I had no idea peer dependencies existed. In my case however I am not sure this is what I am after. I really want to just drop a module into a specific folder and have it 'installed'. With peer dependencies I would have to specify each plugin in my app file as they don't live in the same folder they live as a peer in the same directory as my core server.

Comment: Your answer also leads me to believe that symlinks work on unix systems. However I have found that not to be true because when I try and require a module that lives in my core server from my plugin ('../foo') require cannot not find it as require goes up one dir from from the plugin directory not the symlinked directory.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the nuances of require and symlinks. I don't quite understand what you mean about the peer dependency setup. All I do to load shotgun plugins is go up one directory from the directory shotgun lives in (this is usually node_modules for whatever project installed shotgun). I then search that directory for all directories starting with "shotgun-", which is the convention I use to identify shotgun plugins; though that could be package.json metadata if I didn't want the naming convention to be strict :)

Comment: So in my setup, it's a lot like "dropping in" a plugin. Except I "drop" them into node_modules side by side with shotgun and that's where shotgun knows to look for them. The added benefit of this is the ability to `npm install shotgun-plugin` which just drops the plugin in the node_modules folder while simultaneously ensuring the main package is already installed :)